# Como puedo solucionar este error "ld.exe Cannot find -lbgi"

Tags: c++

estoy empezando a trabajar GUI en Codeblocks C++ con graphics.h, winbgim.h y libgbi.a, configure el compilador tal y como me explica la documentación (info.txt), adicionando las directivas y la librería libbgi.a, por qué me sale este error cuando compilo un programa aunque no use las librerías graficas?

Comment: El mensaje lo dice claro, "No puede encontrar bgi". ¿has probado pasando `-llibbgi` como parámetro?

Comment: Segui tu sugerencia agrege -llibbgi y al error anterior me agrego "ld.exe cannot find -llibbgi"

Comment: Entonces puede ser un tema de que no sabe dónde buscar los archivos para enlazar.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Para ganar en claridad :

Comment: Aclarando mejor mi problea:  Bien estoy comenzando a trabajar en c++, escogí el IDE Codeblocks, en programas de consola todo marcha bien, decidí continuar avanzando y me dispuse aprender a programar con GUI, me descargue el paquete winAPI, configure como explica el documento , sin problema (((( descomprimí, WinBGIm_Library6_0_Dec2017.rar, luego continué tal como explica en Info.txt)))), a partir de ahí el codeblocks me da el mensaje “ ld.exe      cannot find –lbgi” y en la línea de abajo “error: ld returned 1 exit status” aunque solo sea visualiza un cartel

Comment: en pantalla sin GUI me refiero al clásico “ Hello Word”, todo ocurrio loego de configurar el compilador con 
Other linker options:
-lbgi -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32

Comment: el Code::Blocks es la version 20.03 y el compliador C++ es MinGW con gcc-8.1.0 todo a 64 bit